# Lookup based on minimum value by category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to find the location with the large amount of shortage for tools across multiple locations, and then apply that in a new column or measure so that any location I look at, I can see who has the biggest shortage and recommend to a garage with overage to ship to that location.

I have a data set with Tool Number, Locations, Overage/Shortage
I am trying to add which location has the largest shortage, and I not managed to apply this as a measure or column.

Data Example:

- Tool   | Location  | Overage/Shortage
- X-001  | Miami     |  10
- X-001  | New York  |  -7
- X-001  | Boston    |  -4

So my max shortage I can get is -7, but when I try to apply lookup using tool and over/short it gives me errors, and if I use the follow, it would return New York, but just for the row with New York

```
GarageWithShortage = 
VAR SearchValue = CALCULATE(
        MIN(ToolExchage[Overage / Shortage]),
        FILTER(ToolExchage, ToolExchage[TOOL_NUMBER_FW] = EARLIER(ToolExchage[TOOL_NUMBER_FW]))
    )
RETURN
    IF(SearchValue = 0,
    BLANK(),
        CALCULATE (
            SELECTEDVALUE (ToolExchage[Yard Name] ),
            FILTER (
                ALL(ToolExchage[Overage / Shortage]),
                ToolExchage[Overage / Shortage] == SearchValue
            ),
            ALL ( ToolExchage[Yard Name] )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

Measure 1,
Garage with shortage = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Shortage]), ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Tool]))

Column 1,
MCheck = IF([Garage with shortage]='Table'[Shortage], "Yes", "No")

Screenshot,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/efGeC.png